# A shortened association

Tags: associations

```
list =
 {{"aar", "usa", "aer", "NYSE:AIR"}, {"aar", "bel", "sto","F:AIR"}, {"activision", "usa", "sof", "NASDAQ:ATVI"}, {"adidas", "deu", "sto", "F:ADS"}};

AssociationThread[list[[All, 1]] -> Map[Rest, list]]
```

> <|"aar" -> {"bel", "sto", "F:AIR"},   "activision" -> {"usa", "sof",
>   "NASDAQ:ATVI"},   "adidas" -> {"deu", "sto", "F:ADS"}|>

Almost perfect, but two questions remain:

How would you write this?

Why do I lose the first entry of my list?

Comment: What is an expected result?

Comment: Right.  "Almost perfect" means nothing to us unless you tell us what *is* perfect.

Comment: Perfect means that the missing first entry should be "aar" -> {"usa", "aer", "NYSE:AIR"}

Comment: from [AssociationThread>>Details](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationThread.html): __If any of the  keys  are repeated, later instances replace earlier ones__

Comment: @kguler So I can't work with duplicate / multiple keys ?

Comment: eldo, so it seems.  [Association >> Details](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html)  says __If there are multiple elements with the same key, all but the last of these elements are dropped. Merge yields instead a list of values for repeated keys.__

Comment: ... not exactly the output you want but you may consider  `Merge[Thread[list[[All, 1]] -> Map[Rest, list]], Identity]` or `Merge[Thread[list[[All, 1]] -> Map[Rest, list]],Join@@#&]`

Comment: 1000 thanks !!! Merge[Thread[list[[All, 1]] -> Map[Rest, list]], Identity]  is exactly what I was looking for. Please turn this into an upvoteable answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the docs [AssociationThread>>Details](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationThread.html):

> If any of the keys are repeated, later instances replace earlier ones.

And [Association >> Details](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html):

> If there are multiple elements with the same key, all but the last of
>   these elements are dropped. *Merge* yields instead a list of values for
>   repeated keys.

```
Merge[Thread[list[[All, 1]] -> Map[Rest, list]], Identity]
(* <|aar->{{usa,aer,NYSE:AIR},{bel,sto,F:AIR}},
     activision->{{usa,sof,NASDAQ:ATVI}},
     adidas->{{deu,sto,F:ADS}}|> *)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know you are going to get duplicate keys you should consider having a full set of keys for your association.

```
list = {{"aar", "usa", "aer", "NYSE:AIR"}, {"aar", "bel", "sto", 
"F:AIR"}, {"activision", "usa", "sof", "NASDAQ:ATVI"}, {"adidas", 
"deu", "sto", "F:ADS"}};

header = {"company", "country", "stock type", "ticker"};

AssociationThread[header -> #] & /@ list
```

Then if you can pull keys and values far more flexibly - also consider turning it into a `Dataset` for more flexible querying.