# Aliases for keys?

Tags: syntax, associations

The syntactic sugar for alternatives in replacement rules is clean:

```
{a|b|c-> 1, d->2}
```

Are there any analogous shorthands for keys in associations. I want to specify multiple equivalent keys in an association, like this:

```
<| Key[a|b|c]-> 1, Key[d]->2|>
```

The motivation is that sometimes the values in key-value pairs are large (and so you'd rather not flatten it out and add duplicate them for each key alias).

```
$ChordFormulas = <|"Major"|"Maj"->{0,4,7}, "m"|"Minor"|"Min" -> {0,3,7}, "9"|"79"->...|>
```

**Related:**

- [A shortened association](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79430/a-shortened-association/79437#79437)

Comment: How do you want to use these associations?  Are they constants or do you update (change) them frequently?  If they are constants, `Dispatch` (or just a rule list) would work very well, I think.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have already done it with `Alternative`.

```
c = <|"Major" | "Maj" -> {0, 4, 7}, "Minor" | "Min" -> {0, 3, 7}|>;
```

You would just need `KeySelect` and `MatchQ`.

```
KeySelect[MatchQ[#]@"Major" &]@c
(* <|"Major" | "Maj" -> {0, 4, 7}|> *)
```

or with `ReplaceAll`.

```
KeySelect["Maj" /. # -> True &]@c
(* <|"Major" | "Maj" -> {0, 4, 7}|> *)
```

Comment: ```In[211]:= <|"Major" | "Maj" -> {0, 4, 7}|>["Major"]
Out[211]= Missing["KeyAbsent", "Major"]```

Comment: With this approach, everytime I do a query I'll need to use MatchQ which is slow.

Comment: @M.R. Only way I can think of at the moment. It does allow you to use `Alternatives` and store the value once like you asked.

Comment: @M.R. You can use `ReplaceAll` instead of `MatchQ`.  `"Maj" /. # -> True &`.  However, that will fall down if you ever use `True` as a key.